# Create new page layout on communication "modern" site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

I am trying to figure out a way to apply a new layout to the communication site on SharePoint Online. I do not want to go the route of creating a publishing site.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot change the page layout on a Modern site

Answer (score 1):

To edit the page layout, open the Modern Page aspx in SharePoint Designer and look for the tag:

```
<mso:PageLayoutType msdt:dt="string">Home</mso:PageLayoutType>
```

Comment: Hi Michael! Are You abke to define Yoyr custom zones for modern pages?..